# Определение элемента при onclick

Tags: javascript

Есть следующий код JS, который вызывает обработчик onclick

```
var imagejs = document.getElementsByClassName("image");

for (var i=0; i<imagejs.length; i++) {
     imagejs[i].onclick = function (){
        console.log(i); }
}
```

И неопределенное количество элементов с классом image. Но когда возникает событие (на любом элементе) в консоли отображается полное количество элементов с классом image, а не тот, на котором сработал onclick. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как определить элемент?

Comment: используй `this`

Comment: `console.log(this);`

Comment: Возможно вы не поверите, но я пользовался this и это не работало, а сейчас заработало. Благодарен вам.